# Cannot load custom controller in Opencart 2

Tags: php, ajax, opencart2.x

I have created a custom controller in `"admin/controller/mycustomcontroller/mycustomcontroller.php"` to handle some **AJAX requests** among other things for my back-end modules. This custom controller contains an `add()` method that I intend to use.

**Situation:**

- I gave read/write permissions to the Administrator user group.
- Calling the `add` method of my custom controller through AJAX works fine.
- Same as accessing it directly through url `route=mycustomcontroller/mycustomcontroller.php/add`

**Problem:**

- I cannot load the controller using:

  ```
  $this->load->controller('mycustomcontroller/mycustomcontroller/add');
  ```

  I tried to load it in the `admin/controller/catalog/product.php` file and inside my model file but it returns nothing (no result, no error, nothing).

I am new to Opencart and I don't know what's the problem, in the worst case scenario I will just cURL the controller file but that doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tests I finally found the problem, and it's quite silly.

Let's say you want your controller to return an encoded `json` string so that you can use it in your javascript, you could write (by habit):

```
$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($result));
```

Big mistake! Setting the output through this function won't be taken into account when the `load->controller()` method is called, so even though your AJAX/JS will still work fine, nothing else will. instead use:

```
return json_encode($result)
```

The fact that no one had stumbled upon this issue before astonishes me, I am either stupid or missing something important in OC documentation.